Unable to load asset on android device
I worked on my project using the web version, and it was working nicely. However, when I built the APK version, I encountered errors saying "unable to load asset: 'xxxxxxx'" everywhere I used images.
I set up the pubspec.yaml correctly, and it works fine on the web app.
I tried running flutter clean, but it did not resolve the issue

Can you add minimal reproducible code example?
